# GWT - RichTextArea - how to reset text and keep formatting

Tags: gwt

I tried to make a reset functionality for RichTextArea in GWT 2.3 but I faced two problems as

- A) RichTextAarea contains formatting
- B) If I setText("") the formatting is becoming a default one

Maybe I missed something :S So my question is... is there a standard way of **reset** functionality in RichTextArea?

Comment: Oh... Is it really so impossible? Can somebody give a piece of advice please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to select all and then replace it with an empty string

Comment: replace? Is there the method?

Comment: How to 'replace'? Could you give more details?